# Using Two Computers To Create a Network Attached Storage System

Tags: linux, networking, nas, webserver

I currently have two machines each of which contains 2, 250GB drives. One of them has two network ethernet cards. I am hoping to use these two machines to create a 1TB file server for backups. I am looking for some help getting started in this endeavor. What (linux) OS should I use? Is is possible to connect these two machines together without using a switch? If so, how would I do that? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Connect two machines together using a Crossover cable.

Use whichever Linux flavour you are most familiar with (Ubuntu is probably a good choice, but I prefer Debian)

You will set up a Samba/smb share on your server and configure various controls in /etc/samba/samba.conf

my smb.conf I use:

`[media]
path = /srv/store/1T
public = yes
writable = yes
comment = Debian samba/smb media share
printable = no
guest ok = yes`

You <del>mount</del> map this in windows explorer using `\\X.X.X.X\media`

This is answer only highlights key points in this process. You would of course need to fill in the blanks, and adapt to your own implementation. Though you should now have some food for thought (or google) :)

Comment: Depending on the capabilities of the network cards you may not need a crossover cable(Auto MDIX). Try a standard network cable and look for link lights.

Comment: [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html) that's a more comprehensive tutorial on samba. I've done the same thing with a Raspberry Pi and usb storage.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to ask what you planned on doing with this setup but I'm guessing this is a learning exercise utilizing excess hardware. You could look into options like FreeNAS, ClearOS, Zyental, or other specialized distros which normally provide some sort of GUI to set things up. This will get you started on the concepts and allow you to explore a variety of services NFS, Samba, etc. without having to dive directly into the man pages.

I would suggest you look at/learn software RAID for your setup. When you lump space together(RAID 0, striping) you increase your chances of data loss since a single drive failure may make the rest of your data unreadable. With RAID you give up capacity to add redundancy. You could mirror(RAID1) the hard drive in each system which would reduce your total capacity to 500GB but you would be able to recover from drive failures without data loss. If you put all four drives in one box you could do a RAID 5 and get 750GB of space.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to purchase a raspberry pi and setup a samba share for networked attached storage.

**Performance:** I get around 6MB/s down internally - this is enough for streaming HD content.

**Pros:** Easy to setup and low hardware and running cost.

**Cons:** bottleneck for multiple file transfers i.e. can only stream one HD movie at a time.